# mongodb terminal - $push/$pull - SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell)

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add and update a simple data, what is wrong with my request ?

I'm using the website https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal

[image]

---

**#1**

`db.Vendor.find()`

---

**#2**

```
 db.Vendor.insert({
    employee: [ 
       ObjectId('fffffa000000000000000002'),
       ObjectId('fffffa000000000000000003')
    ]
 });
```

---

**#3**

```
db.Vendor.update({
  "employee": ObjectId("fffffa000000000000000002")
}, {
  $push: {
     "employee" : ObjectId("fffffa000000000000000004")
  }
});
```

Comment: Which version? If I copy-paste your snippets I get `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })`  in 3.6

Comment: `db.version()` gives me `3.2.4` on the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's jdoodle terminal specific I guess. The document should be a valid json, not just a js object as in the cli mongo shell.

```
db.Vendor.update({
  "employee": ObjectId("fffffa000000000000000002")
}, {
  "$push": {
     "employee" : ObjectId("fffffa000000000000000004")
  }
});
```

does the job.

Comment: Thx for the check on your conf :)